# CheckBox.setChecked() causes crash; CheckBox variable not initializing, always null?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a dialog that contains several checkboxes. When the dialog is created the boxes should be initialized as checked/unchecked according to the state of designated boolean variables. The variable check passes fine, but when I use CheckBox.setChecked(true/false) it crashes the app.

After a bit of research and playing around i've noticed that the Widget variable I'm using to point to the checkbox isn't getting initialized, though I have no idea why. I connect it with the corresponding id, but it doesn't seem to stick. Even stepping through the code, immediately after my findViewbyId() call the variable shows as null. I have no idea why.

(Although there are 5 checkboxes, I'm going to show the code for just one since they're all functionally identical)

MatrixActionActivity.java

```
public class MatrixActionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    private CheckBox mHotSimCheck, mPublicCheck, mNoiseCheck, mDiffGridCheck, mSilentCheck;
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actions);

        mHotSimCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_hotsim); // <-- mHotSimCheck registers as null even after this statement

        //This button opens preferences dialog
        mPrefsButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MatrixActionActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = MatrixActionActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_matrix_action_modifiers, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);


                final MyDeck deck = MyDeck.getInstance();
                if(deck.isDiveDPActive) {
                    Toast.makeText(MatrixActionActivity.this, "deck.isDiveDPActive = true.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // <-- shows fine when next statement is removed
                    mHotSimCheck.setChecked(true); // <-- Causes crash
                }else{
                    mHotSimCheck.setChecked(false);
                }

                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Dice Pool Modifier Preferences");
                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //nada
                    }
                });
                dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //nada
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                b.show();
            }
        });
```

dialog_matrix_action_modifiers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_hotsim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="+2 while in hot sim"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

</LinearLayout>
...
```

Comment: Post the crash log.

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: please check my edit and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `null` because the `xml` in your `setContentView` is **activity_actions** and the xml that contains checkbox is **dialog_matrix_action_modifiers.xml** , so obviously it will get null on your `checkbox`

after you build your dialog

```
mHotSimCheck = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_hotsim);
```

don't forget to remove this line after setcontentview

```
mHotSimCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_hotsim);
```

**NB**

where did you instantiate your variable `mPrefsButt`?

Comment: Are you saying that "findByView" only checks for IDs in the xml designated in setContentView? How do I get it to connect with an ID in the dialog layout "dialog_matrix_action_modifiers"?  I just tried making "mHotSimCheck" a local variable inside the mPrefsButt.onClick block along with all the other dialog code, but there's no change.

Comment: yes findviewbyid check the xml in the set ctontent view , to achieve what you want check my edit

Comment: Bingo! When I tried initializing inside dialog, I neglected to call findViewById from dialogView. I understand now why that's necessary. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is not contained in the activity's xml, so that `findViewById()` returns null.
You must initialize the `CheckBox` inside `onClick()` after you create `dialogView`:

```
mHotSimCheck = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_hotsim);
```

Comment: Hmm, that's what I just tried - no change. mHotSimCheck still shows as null after.

Comment: *no change* meaning? Is `mHotSimCheck` still null? Or something else?

Comment: In my answer I mention: *You must initialize the CheckBox inside onClick()*

Comment: I was neglecting to call findViewById from dialogView. It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Why? This was the recommendation. When you said *that's what I just tried* what did you mean? You can't use dialogView outside onClick. So you did not try it.